# merge two columns pandas dataframe into one string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['yes',8],['yes',7],['no',np.nan],['yes',7],['no',np.nan]],columns=['passed','score'])

Out[8]: 
  passed  score
0    yes    8.0
1    yes    7.0
2     no    NaN
3    yes    7.0
4     no    NaN
```

and I would like to merge the columns passed and score into only 1 column as follow

```
Out[10]: 
  passed
0  yes_8
1  yes_7
2     no
3  yes_7
4     no
```

my attempt is `df["passed"].map(str) + '_' + df["score"].map(str)` but it is not as clean as I would want
could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Using `df.apply` with `axis=1`

**Demo:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['yes',8],['yes',7],['no',np.nan],['yes',7],['no',np.nan]],columns=['passed','score'])
df["New"] = df.apply(lambda x: "yes_{}".format(int(x["score"])) if x["passed"] == "yes" else "no", axis=1)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  passed  score    New
0    yes    8.0  yes_8
1    yes    7.0  yes_7
2     no    NaN     no
3    yes    7.0  yes_7
4     no    NaN     no
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `+` and `pandas.DataFrame.apply`:

```
df['merged']=df['passed'].astype(str)+'_'+df['score'].fillna(' ').astype(str)
print(df['merged'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('_ ','').split('.')[0]))
```

Output:

```
0    yes_8
1    yes_7
2       no
3    yes_7
4       no
Name: merged, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dropna.html) for remove `NaN`s, convert to `int` and then to `string`s and last [`add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.add.html) to column:

```
a = '_' + df['score'].dropna().astype(int).astype(str)
df['passed'] = df['passed'].add(a, fill_value='')
print (df)
  passed  score
0  yes_8    8.0
1  yes_7    7.0
2     no    NaN
3  yes_7    7.0
4     no    NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so:

```
df['passed'] = (df['passed'] + '_' + df['score'].fillna('').astype(str)).str.rstrip('_')
```

Output:

```
    passed  score
0  yes_8.0    8.0
1  yes_7.0    7.0
2       no    NaN
3  yes_7.0    7.0
4       no    NaN
```